# How to pull data from structured data to Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a solution with which I could transfer data from the code below to variables in google tag manager. I need help writing JavaScript code to help me send the given headline to a variable:

```
<script type = "application / ld + json"> 
{"@context": "https://schema.org", 
"@type": "NewsArticle", 
"headline": "" The best mind of a generation. "Five Years ago Frank Ocean published "Blonde", 
"url": "xxx", 
"thumbnailUrl": " xxx":
</script>
```

I have code that works when retrieving data from meta from this code:

```
<meta name = "author" content = "XXX YYY" />
```

I used:

```
function () {
  var metaName = "author";
  var metas = document.getElementsByTagName ('meta');
  var content = undefined;
  
  for (i = 0; i <metas.length; i ++) {
     if (metas [i] .getAttribute ("name") == metaName) {
          content = metas [i] .getAttribute ("content");
     }
  }
  return content;
}
```

and it worked, you might find it helpful to fix the problem.

Comment: Your structured data seems incomplete. Could you provide an example to work with? How should your data be structured when sending it to GTM? Are you looking for specific values or do you just want to send everything?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier our full strucutred data here: https://validator.schema.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fnewonce.net%2Fartykul%2Fnajlepszy-umysl-pokolenia-piec-lat-temu-frank-ocean-wyda-blonde 

I would like to send the following values:
- headline
- articleSection

Answer (score 1):

The content inside of the `<script>` tag is structured as JSON, which is a format that JavaScript can decode and parse into a workable format.

Select the script and read the `text` property. That property will contain be a JSON string. Decode that string with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

The result will now be an object from which you can select the data.

```js
const script = document.querySelector('script[type="application/ld+json"]')

try {
  // Parse JSON string to object.
  const data = JSON.parse(script.text)
  
  // Select headline and articleSection properties.
  const { headline, articleSection } = data
  
  // Log the values.
  console.log('headline: ', headline)
  console.log('articleSection: ', articleSection)
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "NewsArticle",
    "headline": "„Najlepszy umysł pokolenia”. Pięć lat temu Frank Ocean wydał „Blonde”",
    "url": "https://newonce.net/artykul/najlepszy-umysl-pokolenia-piec-lat-temu-frank-ocean-wyda-blonde",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://cdn.newonce.me/uploads/images/41553/schema_meta_data_Frank_Ocean.jpg",
    "datePublished": "2021-08-20T14:21:55.810+02:00",
    "articleSection": "zagraniczny rap",
    "creator": "Marek Fall",
    "keywords": ["Frank Ocean"],
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
      "@type": "WebPage",
      "@id": "https://google.com/article"
    },
    "image": [
      "https://cdn.newonce.me/uploads/images/41553/schema_meta_data_Frank_Ocean.jpg"
    ],
    "dateModified": "2021-08-20T15:00:47.693+02:00",
    "author": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Marek Fall"
    },
    "publisher": {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "newonce",
      "logo": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https://newonce.net/logo-net.png"
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Side note: The script presented here uses "moder" JS features, which are apparently not supported by GTM. So, instead of `const`, you need to use `var`. Instead of destructuring, you need to pull out the properties one by one.